# Double click not working as expected in file manager

Tags: mouse, filesystem, directory

I have Ubuntu 14.04 installed on my laptop. I have a Dell XPS l502x which works very good.
I just noticed this (possible bug?) with Ubuntu 14.04 while in the file manager in the home folder.
When I try to double click on any folder, it does not open. But double click works every where else.
I was having the similar problem with Ubuntu 13.10 in my home folder, where backspace
was not working to navigate to previous folder.

Comment: I just edited your question to try to make sense of it. I had to guess what you meant in some places. Please let me know if I guessed wrong. Also, your question is not clear (even now). If you could clarify what on exactly what you were expecting to happen and what happens instead (instead of "it doesn't work") would help people help you.

Answer (score 0):

You should find an option to enable double click binary execution in the [Behavior section](http://linux.about.com/library/gnome/blgnome6n12b.htm) of the `Nautilus` file manager; please note that every Linux system can have different/multiple file managers installed, Nautilus itself (the default in Ubuntu) can be replaced if necessary.
If the file manager can't execute a file (shows a message or requires more instructions to open a binary file) you need to enable the EXEC bit on the file attributes: if from the file property dialog you can't enable the execution right checkbox, start a terminal (CTRL+ALT+T or use `xterm` directly) and write `sudo chmod +x YOUREXECUTABLEFILE`.
You may be asked to insert your user password, feel free to trust the request in this case.

Please, feel free to comment under here if you have more questions and don't forget to press the left UP arrow if I'm of any help.

Have a nice experience with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Go to dconf Editor:

*dconf* → *org* → *gnome* → *nautilus* → *preferences* → *click-policy*